# Why am I not getting a refresh-token for when I ask for an access token?

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api

I am using the python-youtube SDK to upload videos to Youtube but first I need to authenticate

Here is the authentication code.

```
cli = Client(client_id="[my client id]", client_secret="[my client secret]")
# Get authorization url
print(cli.get_authorize_url())

# Copy the redirected url after login in.

print(cli.generate_access_token(authorization_response="[link from redirect]"))
# response = AccessToken(access_token='token', expires_in=3599, token_type='Bearer')

cli = Client(access_token="[Access token from previous response]")
```

On the docs it says that I should get a refresh token but knowhere on the responses does it come up.

Answer (score 0):

If your using web app credentials then you only get a refresh token back on the first call.  Google expects you to store the refresh token.

The only way to get one after that is to do prompt force or to revoke the access though the users google account, or the revoke endpoint.

Then the user will be prompted for consent again and you should get a new refresh token.

Comment: Even when I try with a new email address I don't get a refresh token... And I always get prompted for consent even if it is the same email...

Comment: Does it pop up and request consent of the new user?

Comment: Yes it does every time, regardless if I have already given consent.